# Какое различие между процессной виртуальной машиной и системной?

Tags: ос

Добрый день! Какое различие между процессной виртуальной машиной и системной? Пытался читать в разных источниках, все равно полного понимания нет..

Comment: В моем понимании процессная ВМ грубо говоря приложение, которое мы можем запустить, и уже из него запустить какую то конкретную программу (как игру в эмуляторе)
А системная ВМ это полноценная система (какую мы можем установить на Virtual Box)
Верно ли это?

Comment: Почитай вот это [ask]. Дополняйте ваш вопрос согласно [рекомендациям по ведению дискуссий на Stack Overflow](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/691/6), вместо публикации комментариев.